# Decoding Talend Expression into Java Formula

Tags: java, talend

We have a Talend job in Open Studio with the below formula in the expression:

```
row1.Avg_Cost==null?null:
(
  (
     (row1.IND_Price==null||row1.Avg_Price==null)?
     row1.Avg_Cost:(
                     row1.Avg_Cost.multiply(
                                                (row1.Avg_Cost.multiply(new  BigDecimal(0.6))).add(row1.IND_Price.multiply(new BigDecimal(0.4)))
                                               ).divide(row1.Avg_Price,   java.math.RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
                    )
 ).subtract(row1.IND_Spending==null?(new BigDecimal(0.0)):row1.IND_Spending)
)
```

I decoded this formula and ran through a simple java program to:

Avg_Revenue = AVG_COST * ((AVG_COST + IND_PRICE)/AVG_PRICE)

When I plug in the below values,:

```
   double AVG_COST = 26363.05462;
    double AVG_PRICE = 26269.28416;
    double IND_SPENDING = 3101;
    double IND_PRICE = 26083;
```

Talend gives me: 23243.73808 as Revenue.
   Decoded java program gives me: 26550.2653

So, hoping someone here can point out what I am doing wrong in decoding the forumla?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Missed the fact that cost and price were being multiplied by 0.6 and 0.4 respectively. Makes all the difference.
Now, why it was coded this way, is anyone's guess - no business logic here.

Is there a Java BigDecimal/conversion Logic?